# How to insert data in SQLite table using php?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I am working on a php code as shown below which scans the directory **($src_dir)** and list all mp4 files.

```
$src_dir = ('\\\ABCD-ST-001\Audio_Test\podcast\incoming_folder'); 

$mp4_files = preg_grep('~\.(mp4)$~', scandir($src_dir));

print_r(array_values($mp4_files));  // LineA
```

Here is the **O/P** obtained from **Line#A**:

```
Array ( [0] => 36031P.mp4 [1] => hello.mp4 )
```

I am getting two values at Index **0** and Index **1**. The 1st is **36031P.mp4** and 2nd is **hello.mp4**

After that I have wrote a script which insert data in table `Podcast_Export`.

```
$db->exec("INSERT INTO Podcast_Export ('House#', 'Status') VALUES ('array_values($mp4_files)', 'Go')");   /* have to place this question on SO*/
```

On running the above script, I am getting the following data inside the table which is not I want.

```
array_values(Array) Go
array_values(Array) Go
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the script above so that it inserts the following data inside the table:

```
36031   Go
hello   Go
```

Comment: Are you accessing SQLite with PDO [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) or SQLite [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.exec.php)?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have used the following code to make a connection with SQLite databse     `class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
    function __construct() {
    $this->open('database/Podcast.db');
    }
    }
    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db) {
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {
    echo "Opened database successfully<br>";
    }`

Comment: Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted my question. I showed my effort as well.

Comment: Most downvotes are a hit-and-run thing, so I doubt your comment will ever be read by the perpetrator. Just ignore downvotes, they're a fact of live, you can't please everybody. I'll upvote to compensate. Did you know that upvotes are free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting a string value `'array_values($mp4_files)'` , you just need to remove quotes around this value. something like:

```
$db->exec("INSERT INTO Podcast_Export ('House#', 'Status') VALUES (array_values($mp4_files), 'Go')");
```

But, if you delete the quotes around `array_values` then it will insert following array as a string `Array ( [0] => 36031P.mp4 [1] => hello.mp4 )`

so, its better to use loop here with `$mp4_files` array and insert your data.

**Side Note:**

I suggest you to use different name for `House#` column something like `house_no`.

Comment: I have used the following code in order to insert data in the database and it works.  `foreach ($mp4_files as $value) {
   $db->exec("INSERT INTO Podcast_Export ('House#', 'Status') VALUES ('".$value."', 'Go')");
  }`

Comment: The issue which is now is that when I refresh the page it calls the script again and it will insert in the table many times.

Comment: @flash: as we dont know from where you get this variable `$src_dir` i think u need to add one more query before insert , check either data available of not... this is another question

Comment: @flash: i suggest you to create one another quesiotn with more detail from where you getting data, and close this task , marking acceptence, ...

Comment: I have edited my question. It will give you more information from where I am getting `$src_dir`

Comment: @flash: updating question is not a good apprach for future visitors, but u need to use one query before insertiion like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Podcast_Export WHERE House# = '".$value."' AND status = 'GO'` if data exist do not execute insert query else executed

Comment: I have posted a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672664/how-to-avoid-adding-redundant-data-in-sqlite-table-using-php). It would be too much in a comment.