# How to avoid adding redundant data in SQLite table using php?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I am working on a php code as shown below which lists all the **mp4 files** present in a **$src_dir**.

```
$src_dir = ('\\\ABCD-ST-001\Audio_Test\podcast\incoming_folder'); 

$mp4_files = preg_grep('~\.(mp4)$~', scandir($src_dir));

print_r(array_values($mp4_files));  // LineA
```

Here is the **O/P** obtained from **Line#A**:

```
Array ( [0] => 36031P.mp4 [1] => hello.mp4 )
```

Now, I have used the following script in my php code in order to insert those mp4 files in `Podcast_Export` table.

```
    foreach ($mp4_files as $value) {
        $db->exec(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Podcast_Export WHERE House# = '".$value."' AND status = 'GO');
        $db->exec("INSERT INTO Podcast_Export ('House_number', 'Status') VALUES ('".$value."', 'Go')");    // Line B
    }
```

The above script add the following data inside `Podcast_Export` table:

```
36031.mp4 Go
hello.mp4 Go
```

**Problem Statement:**

The issue which I am facing right now is when I refresh the page, the script at LineB is run again and mp4 files present in a **$src_dir** is added again  inside `Podcast_Export` table as shown below:

```
36031.mp4 Go
hello.mp4 Go
36031.mp4 Go
hello.mp4 Go
```

It should work in a way that once new file comes up inside **$src_dir** then it should add inside `Podcast_Export` table. Let us suppose the new file is **hxz210.mp4** then the content inside `Podcast_Export` table 
should be:

```
36031.mp4  Go
hello.mp4  Go
hxz210.mp4 Go
```

Comment: Modify `House#` so it is a unique value... or change your script so on a refresh it doesn't run again.

Comment: Or check the database forst to see if the `House_Number` already exist

Comment: @user3783243 House# is not a proper column name so I have modified it to 'House_number'. On refresh the script should only run when new mp4 file show up.

Comment: @flash: again i recommend to add a query which will be used to check either record exist or not [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56670536/how-to-insert-data-in-sqlite-table-using-php/56670595?noredirect=1#comment99909705_56670595)

Comment: @devpro I have added in the question. Let me know if it looks good.

Comment: is it PDO?? or SQLLITE?

Comment: I am using SQLite 1st time. I have used the following php code in order to make a connection with SQLite database.     `class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
    function __construct() {
    $this->open('database/Podcast.db');
    }
    }
    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db) {
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {
    echo "Opened database successfully<br>";
    }`

Comment: check answer, i have updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selection is fine, but you need to store result into an variable like:

```
$count = $db->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM Podcast_Export WHERE House_number = '".$value."'"); 
if($count <= 0){ 
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO Podcast_Export (House_number,Status) 
               VALUES ('".$value."', 'Go')");
}
```

Using `querySingle` to get the no of rows in SQLite.

note that, i have chanaged the `House#` to `House_number` here and removed `AND status = 'GO'` clause as all of them having `GO` status.

Comment: The code is not going after the 1st line. I am wondering what is `numRows();` in the code above ?

Comment: @flash using numrows to get no of rows maybe syntax is diff for sqlite isn't it?

Comment: As soon, I comment this line the page starts loading but when I uncomment it the page doesn't load.

Comment: @flash u just need to check either query return result or not maybe u need to use diff. Syntax but logic sams

Comment: @flash yes  ...  ...  Right

Comment: I am using the following code and it didn't work still    
  `foreach ($mp4_files as $value) {
  $result = $db->exec("SELECT * FROM Podcast_Export WHERE House_number = '".$value."'");
    $rows = $result->fetchArray();
      if(count($rows) <= 0){ // if data not exist
   $db->exec("INSERT INTO Podcast_Export ('House_number', 'Status') 
        VALUES ('".$value."', 'Go')");
  }
  }`

Comment: The sqlite_version() I am using is 3.27.2

Comment: @flash I give u two tricks u just need to fetch count ... What is the result of `print_r($rows);exit;` use this before count check and share

Comment: I am getting error at this line $rows = $result->fetchArray(); so I don't think so I would be able to add print_r($rows);exit; to check what is the error.

Comment: I did put this `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);` in my php script but unfortunately for that page need to load/open.

Comment: @flash it means u can find the method to get the query result isn't

Comment: Search how can I fetch the query result in sqlite ... @flash .. Now I am at home will help in morning

Comment: No, I wasn't able to resolve. I tried many solutions on internet but it didn't work.

Comment: @flash: in code, we did a minor mistake here... we forgot to add quotes around SELECT query `$result = $db->exec("SELECT * FROM Podcast_Export WHERE House_number = '".$value."'");`

Comment: @flash: use this line

Comment: And if you check my for loop above in the comment section, I already did that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195282/discussion-between-devpro-and-flash).

Comment: Hi, I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192780/how-to-check-if-a-date-falls-between-two-days-of-a-week). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: @flash This will not work it for 100%, as race conditions are possible , a unique key is required..